# PHPMailer not sending attachment?

Tags: php, phpmailer

I'm using PHPMailer to send customers receipt of their order in a pdf format. PDF creation works like a dream, but it just wont attach it to mail. I've tried to my gmail and my own servers email, but it wont send the attachment. Here's my code:

```
<?php   
//Lähetä tilausvahvistus
require_once('mail/class.phpmailer.php');
$bodytext = '
Olemme vastaanottaneet tilauksenne '. $ordernumber .'. 
Tilaamanne tuotteet löytyvät liitteestä.'
  ;
$email = new PHPMailer();
$email->From      = 'no-reply@xxx.fi';
$email->FromName  = 'no-reply@xxx.fi';
$email->Subject   = 'Olemme vastaanottaneet tilauksenne ' . $ordernumber;
$email->Body      = $bodytext;
$email->AddAddress('christian.nikkanen@gmail.com');
$email->AddAttachment('kuitit/kuitti777.pdf','kuitti777.pdf');
return $email->Send();
?>
```

I've tried relative path and direct path, but no, it wont send.

Comment: try a `if(!$email->Send()){ echo $email->ErrorInfo; }`

Comment: It sends the mail, and wont show any errors, and normally the script is executed via ajax call...

Comment: Might have you set `error_reporting` to off ? Maybe set `$email = new PHPMailer(true)` to get errors as exceptions ?

Comment: @Touki did that, but it just stopped sending the mail.

Comment: Doing a `catch (phpmailerException $e) { echo $e->getMessage(); }` didn't give any result ?

Comment: @Touki umm where should I put that line?

Comment: `$email = new PHPMailer(true); try { ...; $email->Send(); } catch (phpmailerException $e) { echo/return $e->getMessage(); }`

Comment: Probably a path error... Using a variable instead of writing the path fixed it, and I haven't even touched the script itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check that PHP is interpreting your path to the file correctly.  Try sticking the $pathtofile in a session and using that rather than statically assigning (or dumping it to output) so you can ensure it isn't a simple path issue.

Comment: Did that, with static it didn't send anything, but with relative it sended the attachment.

Answer (score 2):

Have you validate your path correctly?

Try to write your path again using $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']